# Como criar componentes no Angular?

Tags: angular

Observem a estrutura do projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pagina `estilo-cadastro.component.html` se encontra dessa forma como podem ver abaixo.

```
<div class="container">
    <form #f="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="salvar(f)">
        <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-12">
                <h1>Novo Estilo</h1>
            </div>

            <app-layout-cadastro-estilo  [estilo]="estilo"></app-layout-cadastro-estilo>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Estou tentando criar um componente com o trecho de código abaixo e não estou conseguindo.

```
<app-layout-cadastro-estilo [estilo]="estilo"></app-layout-cadastro-estilo>

<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-9 ui-fluid">
    <label>Nome do Estilo </label>
    <input pInputText type="text" name="nome" [(ngModel)]="estilo.nome" ngModel #nome="ngModel" required minlength="5">

    <app-message [control]="nome" error="required" text="Informe o Estilo"></app-message>
    <app-message [control]="nome" error="minlength" text="Mínimo de {{ nome.errors?.minlength?.requiredLength }} caracteres"></app-message>
</div>

<div class="ui-g-12">
    <p-footer>
        <button pButton type="submit" label="Salvar" [disabled]="f.invalid"></button>
        <button pButton type="button" label="Novo" class="ui-button-info"></button>
        <a href="javascript:;">Voltar para a pesquisa</a>
    </p-footer>
</div>
```

Esse é o arquivo `layout-cadastro-estilo.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-layout-cadastro-estilo',
    templateUrl: './layout-cadastro-estilo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./layout-cadastro-estilo.component.css']
})

export class LayoutCadastroEstiloComponent  {
    @Input() estilo = [];
}
```

E esse é o arquivo `estilo-cadastro.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastyService } from 'ng2-toasty';
import { Estilo } from './../../core/model';
import { ErroHandlerService } from './../../core/erro-handler.service';
import { EstiloService } from './../estilo.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-estilo-cadastro',
    templateUrl: './estilo-cadastro.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./estilo-cadastro.component.css']
})

export class EstiloCadastroComponent implements OnInit {
    private estilo = new Estilo();

    constructor(
        private estiloService: EstiloService,
        private erroHandler: ErroHandlerService,
        private toasty: ToastyService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {}

    salvar(form: FormControl) {
        this.estiloService.adicionar(this.estilo).then(() => {
            this.toasty.success('Cerveja adicionado com sucesso!');
            form.reset();
            this.estilo = new Estilo();
        }).catch(erro => this.erroHandler.handle(erro));
    }
}
```

Essa é a mensagem de erro que está dando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor, como faço para resolver isso? A mensagem de erro está dando nessa linha de código:

```
<input pInputText type="text" name="nome" [(ngModel)]="estilo.nome"
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece pois o seu `ChildComponent (app-layout-cadastro-estilo)` está tentando acessar uma propriedade declarada no `ParentComponent (app-estilo-cadastro)`, que seria o formulário.

Um dos métodos de resolver isso seria passando o formulário como uma variável para o seu `ChildComponent`, assim:

```
<app-layout-cadastro-estilo [form]="f" [estilo]="estilo"></app-layout-cadastro-estilo>

@Component({
    selector: 'app-layout-cadastro-estilo',
    templateUrl: './layout-cadastro-estilo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./layout-cadastro-estilo.component.css']
})

export class LayoutCadastroEstiloComponent {
    @Input() form: FormGroup;
    @Input() estilo = [];
}
```

E ai no template do seu ChildComponent você define assim: `[disabled]="form.invalid"`.

---

> Obs.: Na verdade o seu erro é nessa linha:
>
> `<button pButton type="submit" label="Salvar" [disabled]="f.invalid"></button>`
>
> Veja a mensagem de erro: `Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined`

Comment: quando eu incluo essa linha  @Input() form: FormGroup; ele gera um errão no console do visual code.

Comment: Verifique se está importando tudo corretamente, eu declarei o type `FormGroup`. Você pode remover e deixar assim: @Input() form; ou importar o `FormGroup`.